# Invalid prisma.courseEnrollment.delete() many to many relation in prisma

Tags: reactjs, next.js, prisma

I have a many to many relation prisma model. I wan to be able to delete a single item in my table but for whatever reason I am able to delete all the data but I cant delete a single item

Current working delete handle:

```
  const student = await prisma.courseEnrollment.deleteMany({
            where: {
                id,
               studentId: id,
            }
       })

const  studentToDelete = await prisma.student.deleteMany({
            where: {
                id,
                studentId: id,
            }
       })
```

But this is not what I want

I tried:

```
  const student = await prisma.courseEnrollment.delete({
            where: {
                id,
               studentId: id,
            }
       })

 const  studentToDelete = await prisma.student.delete({
            where: {
                id,
                studentId: id,
            }
       })
```

Able to manually delete with this:

```
 const student = await prisma.courseEnrollment.deleteMany({
            where: {
                studentId: 58
            }
       })

const  studentToDelete = await prisma.student.delete({
            where: {
                id: 58
            }
       })
```

But I am getting Invalid `prisma.student.delete()` error when handling it on the client side.

handle delete function:

```
const handleDelete = async (id) => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/student/delete/', {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    });
const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
    router.push("/");
};

<button onClick={() => handleDelete(student.id)}>Delete</button>
```

I'm I missing something?

Comment: What is the error exactly? What does it say?

Comment: Could you please share your schema.prisma file as well?

Comment: I got the above endpoint to work now. I forgot to add student id to my handle delete which would check if that id is exist.